# align label properly with a textbox only using css

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, alignment, label

I know reading this title one might thought of the same old story of css but its not the same.
I have a textbox and I have given it placeholder property and applied a css class to it.
Now I have to add a label to mark it a mandatory field.
The problem is because of css, I am not able to place the label on the top right corner of the textbox.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="formwrap">
        <div class="formarea">
            <p class="sub_headline">
                User Details</p>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" class="input" placeholder="First name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter First name" ControlToValidate="txtFname" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


</div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.input
{
    font-family: 'Lato' , sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width: 65%;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 14px 94px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #E96151;
    float: left;
}
```

How can I get rid of it??

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove margin for the textbox and it works.

```
.input
{
    font-family: 'Lato' , sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width: 65%;
    height: 20px;
    /*margin: 14px 94px 0 0;*/
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #E96151;
    float: left;
}
```

Please see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLgLK/) which is in html controls, and if you don't want to edit css class then just override adding `style="margin:0;"` in Textbox.

**Suggestion:** placeholder only works for html input, you can use instead below code which works great.

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" class="input" Text="First Name"
       onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = '';}" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: you have just removed margin: 14px 94px 0 0; but that is not effecting the design. Just i have seen

Comment: Ashwini,thanx for the answer,I just discovered removing margins solved  my problem.

Comment: Also, be nice to your users and add the [AssociatedControlID attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx) to the label.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma Placeholder will work. Textbox control will render the input type=text. `<asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" class="input" Text="First Name" placeholder="adssad"></asp:Textbox>` though it need HTML5 supported browser http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using HTML table in designing the UI for the application.

Take one HTML table and place textbox in one column, and label[Manditory *] in the next column to textbox like this>>

```
 <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMantitory" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: @Freelancer-This is where the problem arise, I am instructed not to use table tag.

Comment: @Khushbu : use div tag, as Shekhar has mentioned in his answer, that will be the best way

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create different parent container for each of your element on then it is possible.

```
<div id="formwrap">
    <div class="formarea">
        <p class="sub_headline">
            User Details</p>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" class="input" placeholder="First name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <div>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label><br />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter First name" ControlToValidate="txtFname" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
     </div>  
</div>
```

and set the style vertical-alignment

Comment: I tries this, but it didn't solve my problem, I think the problem is the top and right margins.But I cannot remove them. So, any other solution??

Comment: @Shekhar-I got the solution.I decreased the margins.